# Removing Joomla from client's server

Tags: joomla, ftp

I've been designing a website for a client. It is since completed and I have the ftp details to upload the site.

It appears they are using software called "Joomla!"

How should I go about removing this and uploading the new site - I only have FTP details and do not have any DNS, domain details or anything else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ask customer to backup and download the old site (Very important as a legal stand point).
2. Look at Joomla's SQL details within configuration.php and take note of details.
3. Delete contents of `public_html` or `www`.
4. Upload new site to same location.
5. If new site uses a DB then use same details obtained from configuration.php with a different prefix.

If you get stuck then you should ask the client for details of the web host so you can contact there support.